# Set class that inherits base class as the working type in a collection

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

`MasterClass` is the base class, `Attachvariable` inherits from this. `Table` stores MasterClass objects.

```
public class Table
{
    private Dictionary<int, MasterClass> map = new Dictionary<int, MasterClass>();

    public bool isInMemory(int id)
    {
        if (map.ContainsKey(id))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void doStuffAndAdd(MasterClass theclass)
    {
        theclass.setSomething("lalala");
        theclass.doSomething();
        map[theclass.id] = theclass;
    }

    public MasterClass getIt(int id)
    {
        return map[id];
    }
}
```

So now this happens:

```
Table table = new Table();
if (!table.isInMemory(22))
{
    Attachvariable attachtest = new Attachvariable(22);
    table.doStuffAndAdd(attachtest);
    Console.WriteLine(attachtest.get_position()); //Get_position is a function in Attachvariable 
}
else
{
    Attachvariable attachtest = table.getIt(22); //Error: Can't convert MasterClass to Attachvariable
    Console.WriteLine(attachtest.get_position());
}
```

Is there any way to make `Table` work with any class that inherits from `MasterClass`, without knowing about that class' existance up front, so that I can still use `doStuffAndAdd(MasterClass theclass)` and also use `Attachvariable` as a return type for `getIt()`.

I can't use `Table<T>` because then doStuffAndAdd can't add a MasterClass object to the Dictionary. There's no way to check if T inherits from MasterClass so that's not suprising... how do I make this work?

```
public class Table<T>
{
    private Dictionary<int, T> map = new Dictionary<int, T>();

    public bool isInMemory(int id)
    {
        if (map.ContainsKey(id))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void doStuffAndAdd(MasterClass theclass)
    {
        theclass.setSomething("lalala");
        theclass.doSomething();
        map[theclass.id] = theclass; //Error: can't convert MasterClass to T
    }

    public T getIt(int id)
    {
        return map[id];
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you do `Attachvariable attachtest = new MasterClass(22);' instead?

Comment: @KevinH. Nope that wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this:

```
public void doStuffAndAdd(MasterClass theclass)
    {
        theclass.setSomething("lalala");
        theclass.doSomething();
        map[theclass.id] = theclass; //Error: can't convert MasterClass to T
    }
```

has to be

```
public void doStuffAndAdd(T theclass)
    {
        theclass.setSomething("lalala");
        theclass.doSomething();
        map[theclass.id] = theclass; //should work 
    }
```

You can check if a class inherits another by doing:

```
if(theclass is MasterClass)
{}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that now I can't use the MasterClass.setSomething() function etc. because T doesn't have them.

Comment: Need to put a constraint on `T` in the class declaration: `public class Table<T> where T : MasterClass`

Comment: add a constraint to T to get that functionality @natli

Comment: You can set a type constraint and safely cast theclass. Or you can check if theclass is MasterClass and do a cast.

Comment: Just a note, if you constrain `T` to `MasterClass`, then you don't need to do any checks internally for `if(theclass is MasterClass)` since it's guaranteed to be at runtime.